# Reset SQL Server default Configuration

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a dedicated OLTP server with SQL Server 2008 R2, 24 CPU Cores and 32 GB RAM. Earlier the SQL Server max memory setting had the default value of 0 - 2147483647 MB. And the ETL(mainly stored procedures) had good performance. But last week, somehow we inadvertently changed the SQL Server Max Memory setting to 0 - 16 GB. And the overall performance of ETL degraded and now it is taking twice the time as earlier. I tried to change it back by manually setting it back to 2147483647, also tried running the below query:

```
EXEC  sp_configure'Show Advanced Options',1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO

EXEC  sp_configure'max server memory (MB)',2147483647;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

But I cannot see the improvement in the performance. I even restarted the server after the changes but no luck. I also tried to reset the settings via Tools-->Import and Export Settings --> Reset all settings, but still no luck. Earlier through task manager, it was showing that SQL server is utilizing 95% of the total memory all the time.Now the memory utilization is very low. I need the earlier setting back.

Can anyone help me, how I can restore the default settings (I cannot reinstall the SQL Server as its already in production and have large amount of data)

Answer (score 0):

Memory setting changes are dynamic and SQL Server will acquire memory as it needs to IF the OS has free memory available. This could take a while but no need to reboot.

When you rebooted, you did at least a couple of things to "reset" performance. For starters, you flushed the data cache so everything SQL Server needs to process your stored procs have to be retrieved from disk. This resolves itself relatively quickly without any additional action. As the SPs are run again, cache gets warmed up.

Second, you also flushed all query plans. This is a bit trickier. Depending on statistics freshness and how your queries were written, you may have had some very efficient plans earlier but the current/new plans are bad (there are a number of reasons for it).

Check to ensure sp_configure shows the correct "run_value". Run through the usual performance and workload monitoring steps. If things get back to "normal", then come back here with specific perf tuning questions.